How can I skip old vulnerabilities and break only with new ones using Snyk scan on Azure DevSecOps?
I am using Snyk scan on Azure DevSecOps.online scan works by I am trying to compares specific snapshot with the actual scan using:
 - task: SnykSecurityScan@1
  inputs:
    projectName: 'POcPipeline'
    serviceConnectionEndpoint: 'conectionSnykAzure'
    severityThreshold: 'low'
    testType: 'app'
    monitorWhen: 'always'
    failOnIssues: false
  displayName: 'Run Snyk Security Scan'

 - script: |
    npm install -g snyk snyk-delta
  displayName: 'Install Snyk and Snyk-Delta Tools'

 - script: |
    ls -la
  displayName: 'List Workspace Files'

 - script: |
    snyk test --json --print-deps | snyk-delta --baselineOrg 93d6123-a3rf-ub0f-yc93-216ecc08a338 --baselineProject 015b7a6-26rw-4e23-br47-74544067c54744d
  displayName: 'Snyk Vulnerability Delta Analysis'

I am trying to use Snyk delta to compare scans but I am getting like typo errors:
Generating script.
Script contents:
snyk test --json --print-deps | snyk-delta --baselineOrg 93d6123-a3rf-ub0f-yc93-216ecc08a338 --baselineProject 015b7a6-26rw-4e23-br47-74544067c54744d
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
/usr/bin/bash --noprofile --norc /home/vsts/work/_temp/0547b0-79a1-41d9-b8a1-b452342ee0.sh
Hint: use debug mode -d for more information
BadInputError: Expected 'snyk test --json' output to contain .vulnerabilities[] property but none was found. Ensure 'snyk test --json' completed successfully.
Please review the available documentation via -h or the README

##[error]Bash exited with code '2'.
Finishing: Snyk Vulnerability Delta Analysis



What's the result when you just run "snyk test --json --print-deps" without the delta piping? Just to see that this step alone succeeds properly.

@MathiasConradt I getting "error": "Authentication failed. Please check the API token on https://snyk.io",  this is in the script ("snyk test --json --print-deps") but the online task "SnykSecurityScan@1" works

The Snyk CLI command "snyk test" requires its own authentication, apart from the plugin/scan task. The Snyk CLI command does not refer to the serviceConnection specified further above (conectionSnykAzure).
Hence you need to run snyk auth <SNYK_API_KEY> beforehand; and make SNYK_API_KEY an env variable.
Related Snyk docs: https://docs.snyk.io/snyk-cli/authenticate-to-use-the-cli

Thanks. Now I am able to authenticate. I was trying to use snyk Delta to compare snapchots and fail only with new vulnerabilities but I a just saw it works only whit the bussiness licence. I'll search you when I get acces to it. many thanks.

Yes, it requires the API which isn't in the Free or Team plan. But regarding Delta: a useful function is also Snyk's PR Checks, which scans for only NEW issues in PRs (whether PR changes, and only those, introduced any new vuln). Not exactly the same as a complete delta analysis, but it does into a similar direction.
By the way: if my answer solved the auth problem, please accept. Thanks

About why snyk CLI authentication failed, Mathias Conradt has given a good explanation.
According to How to authenticate to use the CLI in CI/CD pipelines,

All CLI test commands can automatically recognize the environment variable SNYK_TOKEN and use it for authentication.

You can add a secret variable and set its value to your snyk token in the pipeline.

Then map this secret variable to environment variable:
- script: |
    snyk test --json --print-deps 
  displayName: 'Snyk Vulnerability Delta Analysis'
  env:
    SNYK_TOKEN: $(snykToken)

Result:


here you are using only snyk test but no snyk delta

Here are a few steps you can take to troubleshoot and fix the issue:
1. Verify the snyk test --json Output
Ensure that the snyk test --json command is actually generating valid vulnerability data. You can test this separately by running the following command manually in your environment.
2. Verify Project Has Vulnerabilities
You can ensure the proper setup of Snyk on your project by reviewing the following:
Make sure the correct package manager is being used (e.g., npm, yarn, etc.).
Verify the project is being properly initialized and contains dependencies that can be analyzed by Snyk.
3. Ensure Proper Snyk Test Execution
It’s possible that the snyk test is failing due to misconfiguration. You can try adjusting the snyk test command to include more verbose output for debugging.
4. Check if snyk-delta Is Receiving Valid Input
Make sure that:
a. baselineOrg and baselineProject are the correct IDs for your organization and project.
b. The project already exists in Snyk with baseline vulnerability data.
5. Review Snyk and Snyk-Delta Versions
It's possible that you may be using incompatible versions of snyk or snyk-delta. Ensure both are up to date.
6. Adjust the Workflow
Your workflow should ensure that the snyk test command is executed successfully and produces valid JSON output before passing it to snyk-delta. You might need to add checks in your pipeline to handle cases where no vulnerabilities are found.
Additional Considerations:
Snyk API Configuration: Ensure that the Snyk API is correctly configured, with the right access and project IDs.
Snyk-Delta Compatibility: If you still experience issues, check the compatibility and requirements for snyk-delta with your version of snyk.

I getting "error": "Authentication failed. Please check the API token on snyk.io", this is in the script ("snyk test --json --print-deps") but the online task "SnykSecurityScan@1" works
